# Copiar datos específicos con autofiltro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy tratando de copiar solo los datos filtrados de la columna B de una hoja de cálculo a otra, el inconveniente es que la macro con la que estoy trabajando esta situación pega todos los valores de la tabla comprendida en las columnas B: I desde la fila 3 en adelante, a continuación, muestro el código que estoy ajustando a este caso, si es posible espero su ayuda en este caso

```
    Sub ConditionalCopy()
Set H1 = Sheets("VINCULACION_SV")
Set H2 = Sheets("SEN_CONTENIDO_TABLERO")
j = H2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 3
    With H1
            If .Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                .Range("B3:B3").AutoFilter
                .Range("B3:B3").AutoFilter , Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
                . UsedRange. SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(j, "D"), Cells(j, "D"))
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If 
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: ` . UsedRange. SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(j, "D"), Cells(j, "D")) Esto es lo que tendrías que cambiar. Tu código coge todo. Si solo quieres la columna B, cámbialo

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes, me he puesto a la tarea en ajustar esta línea que me sugerís para conseguir el resultado que quiero, pero lastimosamente no lo he logrado. Sería muy útil me pudieras indicar el procedimiento para probarlo.

Comment: Lo que te comenta Elier es que al utilizar .UsedRange estás "diciendo" a Excel que lo que copias es todo el rango visible de tus datos. Todo el rango visible incluye TODAS las columnas, no la columna B cómo tú necesitas. De ahí que en lugar de UsedRange tengas que definir en su lugar un rango que coja toda la columna B una vez filtrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto debería ayudarte a entender como funciona, te recomiendo poner `Option Explicit` en tus módulos y declarar todas las variables:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConditionalCopy()
    
    'Primer problema, al referenciar una hoja, dale también su libro.
    'He puesto ThisWorkbook, que es el mismo que el que tiene el código.
    'Si quisieras hacer referencia a otro libro que no es el que lo contiene,
    'cambia Thisworkbook por Workbooks("Nombre.Extensión") del libro.
    Dim H1 As Worksheet: Set H1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VINCULACION_SV")
    Dim H2 As Worksheet: Set H2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEN_CONTENIDO_TABLERO")
    Dim j As Long: j = H2.Range("D" & H2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim i As Long: i = 3
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With H1
        If .Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            '.Range("B3:B3").AutoFilter esto te sobra
            .Range("B3:B3").AutoFilter , Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            'Estabas pegando todos los datos en la hoja activa, si la hoja activa era H1
            'te los pegaría en la misma, al poner la referencia de H2 delante, te los pegará
            'donde tú querías sin importar la hoja activa.
            'Al poner el rango de B4 a B y la última fila con datos te pegará el dato que
            'deseas, ya que usedrange coge literal, el rango utilizado, que puede ser toda la hoja.
            .Range("B4:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy H2.Range("D" & j)
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```